# ABCDE: Strings of length $3$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm told that the letters ABCDE are to be used to form string of length $3$, and then I'm asked the following question:

> How many strings contain the letter $A$, allowing repetitions?

---

What I'm wondering is, what is meant by repetitions? Does that mean $AAC$, $DAA$, and so on?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the examples you give would each "count". Indeed, it means that once any letter is used, it can be used again. Essentially, you are being asked how many 3-letter combinations contain at least one "A".

Suggestion:

Compute $T$ = total number of combinations that contain three letters, and compute $N$ = the number of combinations that do not contain *any* A.

The difference given by $A = T - N$ will yield the number of strings containing *at least one* letter A. (That "beat" brute force listing of all strings that contain *at least one* letter "A"!)

Number of $3$-letter strings: $\quad T = 5^3$
Number of $3$-letter strings not containing "A": $\quad N = 4^3$
Number of $3$-letter strings containing at least one letter "A": $\quad T - N = 5^3 - 4^3 = 61$.

Comment: So, in other words, it is saying "with replacement," correct?

Comment: So... It's just $1*5*5$, right?

Comment: Yes, with replacement, and repetition of letters permitted.

Comment: Wait that's not right... It would be $1\cdot 5 \cdot 5 + 1\cdot 5 \cdot 5 + 1\cdot 5 \cdot 5 = 75$, right?

Comment: Think about it a little longer...Your second guess is closer, but we have to subtract twice from that for, say, $AAA$ counted three times in your second guess, and about $ABA$, counted twice in you second guess. There are other combinations that are overcounted in your $3 \times 1\cdot 5\cdot 5$ total. Note that $5\cdot 5\cdot 5 - 4 \cdot 4 \cdot 4 = 61$, if you follow my suggestion.

Comment: I suspect it is $61$...

Comment: Yes, you've got it, Trancot. Did you see my last comment?

Comment: Yes, thank you, amWhy.

Comment: You're very welcome, Trancot.

Comment: What would it then mean if the condition were that repetitions weren't allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of computing the number in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/):

```
Size(Filtered(Tuples(["A","B","C","D","E"],3),l->"A" in l));
```

which returns 61.

Or, to streamline your C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    unsigned answer = 0;

    for( unsigned i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; ++i )
    {
        for( unsigned j = 0 ; j <= 4 ; ++j )
        {
            for( unsigned k = 0 ; k <= 4 ; ++k )
            {
                if( i == 0 || j == 0 || k == 0 )
                {
                    ++answer;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    cout << answer << endl << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The `slot`s are actually the same vector, and are unnecessary in any case.